# Need guidance on efficiently fetching from Django server with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, django, postgresql, backbone.js, chat

I have an app built on Backbone.js and Django that is just something I'm building for practice.

It's a webchat app that let's users post a message and then saves it to a database, all while constantly fetching new data into a collection I have, so it "updates live" with the server.

On a basic level, the front-end application works with a `message` model to model a user's message, a `messages` collection to store all of the posts, and a `chat` view to render the collection in the chat window.

The code I use to constantly fetch new data from the server is:

```
// This code is inside the `chat` view's `initialize` function, 
//   so `that` is set to `this` (the `chat` view) higher up in the code.
window.setInterval(function() {
  theColl.fetch({
    success: function() {
      that.render();
    }
  });
}, 2000);
```

I have don't have `reset: true` because I thought that it would be more efficient to just append new messages to the collection as they were retrieved from the server, instead of reloading every model already in it.

Is this an efficient way to run a simple webchat? As the application has to fetch more models, I've noticed that it gets extremely sluggish, and adds a delay to the user input. Here is a photo to show what I think is one problem (p.s. ignore the stupid messages I wrote):

[image: Chat example]

As the server sends back new models and the collection refreshes, I think that my app is initializing old chat models again, because at this point in the application the collection itself only had 25 models inside of it.

Is there something I can do to stop the reinitialization of every model in the database? As you can see, even though there are only 25 unique models in the chat, and in the database, after letting the app run for 2 minutes or so I get models with CIDs up to 460.

Regardless of that, I've noticed that if I flood the server with new messages things go awry, like new messages appear out of place, and the server gets backed up. The latter may be because I'm using the cheapest option on Digital Ocean to host the app, but I'm not sure what the first problem comes from. It may be from my Django app's `views.py` or the rest of my Backbone code, I'm not really sure how to debug it.

Comment: I would imagine anytime you're hitting the server every 2 seconds, which is hitting the database as well its going to be a heavy load on any single node.  However I had a site running Linode and React.js which was also using polling, I never did any heavy stress tests but it seemed to hold up just fine with a limited amount of users.  As far as chat is concerned, you may want to look at react since dirty checking (new comments etc..) is where it shines.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes Thanks for the advice. The place I'm going to be working at this summer uses Backbone.js so I'm trying to get as much practice with it as I can. Maybe after this summer I can look into React.